# TypeError: missing 1 required positional argument: 'self' but the class is instanciated

Tags: python, typeerror

I am trying to write a Zoo program but I always get the following output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\cisco_2\zoo.py", line 31, in <module>
    ape.vorstellen()
  File "C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\cisco_2\zoo.py", line 26, in vorstellen
    Tier.vorstellen()
TypeError: vorstellen() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Here is the source code:

```
class Zoo:

    def __init__(self,name,rasse):
        self.name = name
        self.rasse = rasse

    def vorstellen (self):
        print ("Hallo, Ich heisse {0} und bin ein {1}".format(self.name,self.rasse))

class Tier (Zoo):

    def __init__(self,name,rasse,kafig):
        Zoo.__init__(self,name, rasse)
        self.kafig = kafig
    def vorstellen (self):
        Zoo.vorstellen()
        print ("Ich wohne in Kaefig {0}".format(self.kafig))

class Affe (Tier):

    def __init__(self,name,rasse,kafig,futter):
        Tier.__init__(self,name,rasse,kafig)
        self.futter = futter

    def vorstellen(self):
        Tier.vorstellen()
        print ("Ich fresse {0}".format(self.futter))

ape = Affe("Chimp","Affe",3,"Bananen")

ape.vorstellen()
```

Does anyone have an idea why I'm getting that error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling the unbound method on the *parent* class:

```
def vorstellen(self):
    Tier.vorstellen()
    print ("Ich fresse {0}".format(self.futter))
```

Add in `self` there:

```
def vorstellen(self):
    Tier.vorstellen(self)
    print ("Ich fresse {0}".format(self.futter))
```

or use [`super()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super) to load the next method in the hierarchy; `super()` binds the method for you:

```
def vorstellen(self):
    super().vorstellen()
    print ("Ich fresse {0}".format(self.futter))
```

This assumes you are using Python 3; in Python 2, `Zoo` must inherit from `object` and you must pass in the current class (by name) and `self` to `super()`:

```
def vorstellen(self):
    super(Affe, self).vorstellen()
    print ("Ich fresse {0}".format(self.futter))
```

Inheriting from `object` makes the `Zoo` class and all subclasses new-style classes. This is the default in Python 3.

Comment: thanks i know it was a stupid thing didnt think it was that stupid though